# how do i stop the table from showing the time in the date column?

Tags: c#, asp.net, calendar

```
 protected void Calendar1_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {   System.Data.DataView view = socialEvents.DefaultView;
        view.RowFilter = String.Format("Date >= #{0}# AND Date < #{1}#",
        Calendar1.SelectedDate.ToShortDateString()); ,                            
        Calendar1.SelectedDate.AddDays(1).ToShortDateString()
                       );
           if (view.Count > 0)
        {
            GridView1.Visible = true;
            GridView1.DataSource = view;
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }
        else
        {
            GridView1.Visible = false;
        }
    }
```

the date in database is of type date, when a calendar date is selected a gridview table appears with that selected date, but it shows that date and a time as well how do i get rid of that time, i want only that selected date to be listed in the gridview [how to remove that time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Irjzf.jpg) ?

```
<asp:Calendar ID="Calendar1" runat="server" BackColor="White" BorderColor="Black" DayNameFormat="Shortest" Font-Names="Times New Roman" Font-Size="10pt" ForeColor="Black" Height="356px" NextPrevFormat="FullMonth" OnDayRender="Calendar1_DayRender" OnSelectionChanged="Calendar1_SelectionChanged" TitleFormat="Month" Width="936px" onclientclick="return false;" autopostback="false" >

</asp:Calendar>

<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" BackColor="White" BorderColor="#336666" BorderStyle="Double" BorderWidth="3px" CellPadding="4" GridLines="Horizontal" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Height="196px" Width="360px">

    <Columns>
   <asp:BoundField DataField="EventTitle" HeaderText="Title" />
   <asp:BoundField DataField="Description" HeaderText="Description"  />
   <asp:BoundField DataField="Date" HeaderText="Date"  />
   <asp:BoundField DataField="Time" HeaderText="Time"  />
   </Columns>
```

Comment: How do you define the GridView1 markup in the ASPX file? Did you set the format there?

Comment: Can you show the markup for your date column? Are you using `autogeneratecolumns="true"`? The code shown has nothing to do with your problem at hand.

Comment: the date is being added from another calendar control !

Comment: <ajaxToolkit:CalendarExtender ID="CalendarExtender1" runat="server" Format="MM/dd/yyyy" PopupButtonID="ImageButton" PopupPosition="BottomRight" TargetControlID="txtdate"  ></ajaxToolkit:CalendarExtender> ..  and the selected date from here goes to the DB and in the asp:Calendar ID="Calendar1" it is shown that there is an event on that day. when it is clicked the gridview shows the info .. of the date and description ...

Comment: try setting the DataFormatString in the markup for that column in the grid.  A quick google came up with this...   https://forums.asp.net/t/1001482.aspx?DateTime+Format+in+gridview+colum

Comment: yep that was the solution thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to set the appropriate formatting for the Date column

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="Date" HeaderText="Date"  DataFormatString="{0:d}"/>
```

In NET you don't have a Date type, you always get a DateTime type. It is the formatting that you apply to this value, when you want to display it, that decides what to show to your user

MSDN: [DateFormatString](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.boundfield.dataformatstring(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: i get an error when i try that out 
..

System.FormatException: Index (zero based) must be greater than or equal to zero and less than the size of the argument list.

Source Error: 


      protected void Calendar1_DayRender(object sender, DayRenderEventArgs e)
         {
           DataRow[] rows = socialEvents.Select(
                  String.Format(
                 "Date >= #{0}# AND Date < #{1}#",

Comment: I am not sure if this has anything to do with the introduction of a formatting option on the grid row.

Comment: ma bad ! yep that was it should have figured it out sooner! thank you for your help